# Seeking cheap electronic note taking device

Tags: ewriter

I am looking for cheap electronic notetaking device.

There are lots of cheap ones, mostly for kids, like this:

[image]

which are dirt cheap and even run for many moths on a watch battery, ***BUT***, I want one that can upload to my PC. I don't care if it's by Bluetooth, WiFi, USB cable, even swapping a micro SD.

Also, I want to be able to save multiple pages. Maybe 10, max 20. I prefer A5 size, which I can stick in a jacket pocket to larger. I don't need meg-drawing capability, just hand writing and occasional sketching.

Cheap & cheerful, please.